# xml in jquery in client side without webserver?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using following code in my html file and run manually not in webserver through double clicking only.it did not parse xml and give correct node value? any help please? how jquery
will work if xml content is big one, because the code i have used is not having callback function, how does it identify all xml data has been recieved before parsing?

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $.get("http://www.hindu.com/rss/01hdline.xml", function(response){
 var response = $.paseXML(response);
  var $xml = $(response);

 //Now you can find any xml node with $xml using various methods of jQuery
 //E.g
  alert($xml.find( "title" ));   
 });
 });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your success handler will not be called, place an alert of see in firebug, because of [**"Same Origion Policy"**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). Also have a look at [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing)

what you can do is make a server side proxy, make request to the Url and get a xml response, then pass back that response to your client side where you can use jquery to parse the xml.

Comment: i am new to java script,what is the difference between same origin and cross origin?

Comment: i am doing in mobile, cant i parse xml without server side communication except url communication?

Comment: yes you can parse it on the client end but you have to get the xml response from the server

Comment: ok.but why my code is not giving output, can u alter to give output?

Comment: your code is not giving the output because you are making a `GET` request from your domain say `http://www.nameless.com` to another domain (cross domain) called `http://www.hindu.com/rss/01hdline.xml` and that is not allowed

Comment: pls how can i set server side proxy? is it not possible cross domain policy without server side proxy please?

Comment: in your case no its not possible

Comment: i have to use ajax to enable it? please

Comment: you can set `crossDomain:true` in your ajax request that can be used if the cross-domain to which you are making request supports it in your case the domain you are querying doesn't support it