# difference between ajax and jquery?

Tags: jquery, .net, html, ajax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what is the difference between ajax and jquery and which one is better?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931908/what-is-the-difference-between-ajax-and-jquery-and-which-one-is-better)

I'm new to Web development. I have few questions

1. is it possible cross-domain policy through ajax without server side proxy for   xmlparsing?
2. forums are saying cross domain policy is not possible through jquery wihout server side proxy?
3. what is difference between ajax and jquery?

Comment: This is an already asked question. Please refer to this POST: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/931908/what-is-the-difference-between-ajax-and-jquery-and-which-one-is-better Hope this helps.

Comment: @nameless you should add reference to your old question that will help to understand the context http://stackoverflow.com/q/7116721/413670

Answer (score 1):

I don't think I really understand either of your first two questions.  For the third question about Ajax and jQuery:

The Wikipedia articles are both [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) and [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery) offer a pretty good summary.

Ajax is a means of sending a request to a web server using javascript and retrieving a response from that server.  Ajax calls can either be used to send data to a server without switching to a new web page or they can be used to retrieve information from a web server (again without switching to a new web page) which can be acted upon by javascript in the page.  Dynamic sites that get new information from the server without changing web pages are usually using Ajax to do so.

jQuery is a cross-browser library with all sorts of useful functionality for manipulating web pages.  Among jQuery's many features is an Ajax library that also makes using Ajax calls easier, but the Ajax support in jQuery is one tiny piece of what jQuery offers.  jQuery is very useful for manipulating web pages (hiding, showing, animating, creating, deleting, styling, finding, validating, etc...) via javascript.

Comment: here is a reference to OP's original question http://stackoverflow.com/q/7116721/413670

Answer (score 0):

1. You can make cross domain requests [using jsonp](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-jsonp/)
2. See 1.
3. ajax is a vague term for asynchronous requests from browsers to web servers. jQuery is javascript library for DOM manipulation and ajax.

I don't know what you mean by 'crossdomain policy'. Googling suggests that this may be a flash thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSOP or CORS to get information across domains.

Answer (score 0):

Although is correct that cross domain request are not allowed for security reasons without a proxy hosted in the domain of the page that initiates the request, there are some tricks and libraries that can help you with that.

Ex: http://easyxdm.net/wp/